# Assembly program to add two 32 bit numbers and display the result on screen

Tags: assembly, x86-16

So this is the assembly code for the program mentioned:

```
.model small
.386p
.data
    n1 dd 12345678h
    n2 dd 11112222h
    res dd ?
.code
.startup
    mov eax, n1
    mov ebx, n2
    add eax, ebx
    mov res,eax
    call disp

    disp proc near
    mov ch,08h
up:
    mov eax,res
    rol eax, 04h
    mov res,eax
    and al, 0Fh
    cmp al, 0Ah
    JC d1
    add al,07h
    d1: add al,30h

    mov dl, al

    mov ah, 02h
    int 21h
    dec ch
    JNZ up

    ret
    endp disp
    mov ah,4ch
    int 21h

end
.exit
```

Would someone be kind enough to explain what the procedure "disp" does exactly step wise? The addition part makes sense though the rest eludes me. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like it's converting the binary value in `Res` a to hexadecimal output and printing that on screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First it rotates the 32-bit value in `res` so that the previous 4 most significant bits end up in the 4 least significant bits:

```
mov eax,res
rol eax, 04h
mov res,eax
```

For example, if `res` held `0x12345678` at the first line, `eax` and `res` would both hold `0x23456781` after the third line.

It then masks away all but the 4 least significant bits of `al`:

```
and al, 0Fh
```

If we continue with my example above, `al` will now contain `0x01`.

It then adds 7 to `al` if `al >= 0x0A` (`JC` can be viewed as `Jump if unsigned less than`), and finally adds `'0'` (0x30) to `al`:

```
cmp al, 0Ah
JC d1
add al,07h
d1: add al,30h
```

If `al` originally was in the range 0..9 it will now be in the range 0x30..0x39 (ASCII `'0'..'9'`). If it was originally in the range 0x0A..0x0F it will now be in the range 0x41..0x46 (ASCII `'A'..'F'`).

Finally it prints the resulting character using `int 21h / ah=02h` (`WRITE CHARACTER TO STANDARD OUTPUT`).

It then repeats this 7 more times (i.e. for every hex digit in the 32-bit input number).

Answer (score 0):

First of all: The sequence

```
mov ah,4ch
int 21h
```

(exit program) is at the wrong place. It must be right before the `disp proc near`.

The procedure `disp` displays the unsigned integer in `res` in hexadecimal notation:

```
disp proc near
    mov ch,08h          ; loop 8 times 'up'
up:
    mov eax,res         ; load value in 'result'
    rol eax, 04h        ; move the highest nibble to the lowest place
    mov res,eax         ; save eax for future use (next pass of 'up')
    and al, 0Fh         ; isolate the nibble
    cmp al, 0Ah         ; al < 0A?
    JC d1               ; yes: skip the next command
    add al,07h          ; add 7 to match the appropriate character ('A' - 'F')
    d1: add al,30h      ; convert AL to ASCII
    mov dl, al
    mov ah, 02h         ; Fn 02h: Write character in DL to Standard Output (Stdout)
    int 21h             ; call MSDOS-interrupt
    dec ch              ; loop 8 times
    JNZ up
    ret
endp disp               ; TASM. For MASM use 'disp endp'
```